# What is wrong with my MathJax square bracket syntax?

Tags: mathjax, asciidoctor

This mathjax expression (in an asciidoctor document in a VS Code preview using [asciidoctor-vscode](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode)) fails to render correctly:

```
stem:[  = x_l = x_( ([m]+1) /2)   ]
```

The ] after the m acts like a ) for the _, and ends it early. How can I force the parser to understand my brackets please?

Answer (score 1):

> If the inline stem equation contains a right square bracket, you must **escape this character using a backslash**.

Found in [Equations and Formulas (STEM)](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/stem/), see example 4. What you want to write is:

```
stem:[  = x_l = x_( ([m\]+1) /2)   ]
```

Answer (score -1):

MathJax is rubbish, rather use `latexmath:[ = x_l = x_{\frac{[m\]+1}{2}} ]`

Comment: You don't need to cast aspersions, and latexmath only side-steps the OP's question without solving it.